# Adding a third table to a Join

Tags: php, mysql

This query works fine:

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT s.loginid, s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, l.username
             FROM submission AS s,
                  login AS l
            WHERE s.loginid = l.loginid
         ORDER BY s.datesubmitted DESC
            LIMIT 10";
```

Would this work if I wanted to join a third MySQL table (called "comment") to it?

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT s.loginid, s.submissionid s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, l.username, count(c.comment) countComments
             FROM submission AS s,
                  login AS l, 
                  comment AS c,
            WHERE s.loginid = l.loginid
              AND s.submissionid = c.submissionid
         ORDER BY s.datesubmitted DESC
            LIMIT 10";
```

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 3):

You should really be using joins, it's more clear and it keeps your join conditions out of your where clause. Also, when you want to add a 3rd table in, it's more consistent:

Here's your original code, using explicit join syntax:

```
SELECT      s.loginid, s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, l.username
FROM        submission s
INNER JOIN  login l ON l.loginid = s.loginid
ORDER BY    s.datesubmitted DESC
LIMIT       10
```

Then, if you want to add a third table, it's easy:

```
SELECT      s.loginid, s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, l.username
FROM        submission s
INNER JOIN  login l ON l.loginid = s.loginid
INNER JOIN  comment c ON s.submissionid = c.submissionid
ORDER BY    s.datesubmitted DESC
LIMIT       10
```

Also, here's a trick. If you the two columns you join on are the same name, you can use the `USING` syntax:

```
INNER JOIN  login l USING (loginid)
INNER JOIN  comment c USING(submissionid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost.

Your syntax is for the third table is correct (although old-style; it uses implicit JOINs).

But to make the COUNT(c.comment) work you must (or I should say "ought to", since MySQL is loose on certain syntax) add a GROUP BY clause to the selection.  That clause should name every other column in the SELECT:

```
SELECT s.loginid, s.submissionid s.title, s.url, 
       s.displayurl, l.username, count(c.comment) AS countComments
FROM submission AS s,
     login AS l, 
     comment AS c,
WHERE s.loginid = l.loginid AND s.submissionid = c.submissionid
GROUP BY s.loginid, s.submissionid s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, l.username
ORDER BY s.datesubmitted DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add a GROUP BY clause with one or more fields in it (I've set just the loginid in the example below) as well as you're using the COUNT() function in there, so the SQL would go something like this:

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT s.loginid, s.submissionid s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, l.username, count(c.comment) countComments
             FROM submission AS s,
                  login AS l, 
                  comment AS c
            WHERE s.loginid = l.loginid
              AND s.submissionid = c.submissionid
         GROUP BY s.loginid
         ORDER BY s.datesubmitted DESC
            LIMIT 10";
```